# drupal views images with different sizes

Tags: views

i want create a views show last news with image and title.
first image news must be 300px * 300px and other news images 150px * 150px .

something like this :
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided. Please read through the links in the [help] to understand what types of question we answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Image Matrix](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagematrix)  module

> Image Matrix module provides Views style plugin and content field formatter for displaying any number of images in magazine-like layout, arranging them at different sizes so that all images fit within a defined "square box".

Sample Image from module page

[image]